# Using trigram language model to estimate probablilites

Tags: probability, markov-process

P(A | B) : probability of event A given event B occurred

A second order Markov model is given as :

[image]

Assume x0 = x-1=* in this definition where * is a special start symbol in the sentence.

An example is then provided which I'm attempting to implement :

```
(the dog barks STOP) = q(the|*, *)×q(dog|*, the)×q(barks|the, dog)×q(STOP|dog, barks)
```

This is based on a nlp course , notes :http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/courses/nlp2011/notes/lm.pdf

Is `q(the|*, *)` the probability of `the` given `* , *` ? 
I'm assuming that `* , *` can be any value, and so `q(the|*, *)` = 1/4 ?

Same assumption based on `q(dog|*, the)` ? How to determine value for `q(dog|*, the)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the '$*$' in this case refers to a special symbol, just like any other word. When you're summing up your trigram frequencies, just imagine that your sentence is prepended with an these '$*$' terms.